# Производительность тегов HTML

Tags: html, оптимизация, производительность, теги

Есть ли разница в производительности между тегами?
Например у меня *(образно)* 10000 слов данных, каждое слово нужно обернуть в тег
Влияет ли выбор тега на производительность, если стили одинаковые?

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">some item</li>
    <li class="item">some item</li>
    <li class="item">some item</li>
</ul>
```

**VS**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">some item</div>
    <div class="item">some item</div>
    <div class="item">some item</div>
</div>
```

(Вопрос не конкретно про эти (`div`, `li`) теги, а про теги вообще)

Comment: что тут имеется ввиду под производительностью?

Comment: @Grundy влияние на скорость отрисовки, загруженность системы, и тд...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для браузера это всего лишь нет никакой разницы в том каким тегом обернуто слово, или что-либо другое.

На производительность будет влиять само количество этих тегов. Google Chrome рекомендует на одной странице использовать не более 1500 тегов в идеальном случае и не более 3000 в худшем случае. Если на странице больше 3000 тегов - уже будет ругаться [Google Page Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU).

По большей части на производительность влияет css. Желательно не делать много селекторов, и не создавать специфичных селекторов. Так же нужно иметь введу то, что анимации css тоже сильно грузят страницу. Об производительности css можно почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/244815/).

Ну и основное, что грузит страницу - это JavaScript.

Так же не стоит никогда заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией.